# CASE in WHERE clause equivalent

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Consider the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM 
   Orders
WHERE
   (AdjShipDate IS NOT NULL OR EstShipDate IS NOT NULL)
    AND
    CASE 
        WHEN AdjShipDate IS NOT NULL THEN AdjShipDate
        WHEN AdjShipDate IS NULL AND EstShipDate IS NOT NULL THEN EstShipDate
    END
    BETWEEN '2011-07-01' AND '2011-07-30'
```

The case's WHEN expressions depend on a value (AdjShipDate) from the table that I'm trying to query.  How would I write a similar query in Linq to SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's essentially a COALESCE:

```
where (o.AdjShipDate ?? o.EstShipDate) >= new DateTime(2011,07,01) 
   && (o.AdjShipDate ?? o.EstShipDate) <= new DateTime(2011,07,30)
```

Though I'm not certain in the ?? operator is supported by Linq-to-SQL.  If it doesn't you could try

```
where (o.AdjShipDate != NULL 
           && o.AdjShipDate >= new DateTime(2011,07,01) 
           && o.AdjShipDate <= new DateTime(2011,07,30))
   || (o.AdjShipDate == NULL && o.EstShipDate != NULL 
           && o.EstShipDate >= new DateTime(2011,07,01) 
           && o.EstShipDate <= new DateTime(2011,07,30))
```

Comment: +1 and COALESCE is supported by Linq to SQL. Only one thing - you should add `(o.AdjShipDate != null || o.EstShipDate != null)` for where statement.

Comment: The null-coalescing operator does work in Linq-to-SQL!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely equivalent to:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM 
   Orders
WHERE
    (AdjShipDate IS NOT NULL and AdjShipDate BETWEEN '2011-07-01' AND '2011-07-30')
     OR
    (AdjShipDate IS NULL and EstShipDate IS NOT NULL ANd EstShipDate BETWEEN '2011-07-01' AND '2011-07-30')
```

Just compile it to LinqToSql.